# how to use 3 variables in PL/SQL function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I try to use 3 local variable in a PL/SQL function, but when a run log shows that 2 are invalid

Following is the code:

```
create or replace function valor_parcela(p_num_venda number, p_juros number)
return number is
    tmp_valor_parcela number(7,2);
    f_num_parcelas number(7,2);
    f_valor number(7,2); 
begin
Select num_parcelas
  into :f_num_parcela
  from VENDS
 where numero=p_num_venda;

Select valor_total
  into :f_valor
  from VENDS
 where numero=p_num_venda;

tmp_valor_parcela := (f_valor/f_num_parcela)*p_juros;
return (tmp_valor_parcela);
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As it already has been said by @REW, variable's name in the `into clause` of a query should not be preceded by a colon.

   ```
   into f_num_parcela  -- without colon
   ```

   and

   ```
   into f_valor
   ```
2. Those two queries could be simply replaced by one:

   ```
   Select num_parcelas
        , valor_total
     into f_num_parcela
        , f_valor
     from VENDS
    where numero=p_num_venda;
   ```
3. You probably could do calculation in the `select` section of the query

   ```
   Select (valor_total / num_parcelas) *p_juros
     into tmp_valor_parcela
     from VENDS
    where numero=p_num_venda;
   ```

But you should guarantee that your query is returning exactly one record, otherwise `too_many_rows` exception will be raised. On the contrary, if the query returns no rows `no_data_found` exception will be raised. So it would be a good idea to include `exception` section in your stored procedure.

Comment: f_num_parcelas, f_valor need to be declared...

Answer (score 3):

Try this too, you'll get the value for num_parcelas and valor_total from a single query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION valor_parcela(
         p_num_venda NUMBER,
         p_juros     NUMBER)
         RETURN NUMBER
IS
     tmp_valor_parcela NUMBER(7,2);
     f_num_parcelas    NUMBER(7,2);
     f_valor           NUMBER(7,2);
BEGIN
     SELECT num_parcelas, valor_total 
       INTO f_num_parcela, f_valor 
       FROM vends 
      WHERE numero = p_num_venda;

     tmp_valor_parcela := (f_valor/f_num_parcela)*p_juros;
     RETURN (tmp_valor_parcela);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

Your local variables don't need to be "bind-variables". Note that the "select into" is now into f_num_parcela and f_valor instead of :f_num_parcela and :f_valor.

```
create or replace function valor_parcela(p_num_venda number, p_juros number)
return number is
  tmp_valor_parcela number(7,2); 
  f_num_parcelas number(7,2); 
  f_valor number(7,2); 
begin
  Select num_parcelas into f_num_parcela from VENDS where numero=p_num_venda;
  Select valor_total into f_valor from VENDS where numero=p_num_venda;
  tmp_valor_parcela := (f_valor/f_num_parcela)*p_juros;
  return (tmp_valor_parcela);
end;
```